# Predicate calculus | finding which structure satisfies a sentence

Tags: logic

I have two structures: $M_1=<\mathbb{Z},P^{M_1}=${2,3}$,<_{\mathbb{Z}}>$ and $M_2=<\mathbb{Z},P^{M_2}=${0,1}$,<_{\mathbb{Z}}>$
$$\phi=\forall y[(y<2) \rightarrow \exists x(P(x) \land (y<x))  ]$$
I need to know, who satisfies $\phi$ and who doesn't if there is someone.

- Ignore the mistake of the-2 in the sentence.

---

I have tried checking, for each structure, when $y>2$ and when $y<2$, but I don't know if this is the way to solve that question, and so I am not sure of my results.

Comment: $M_1$: for each $n \ge 2$ we have that $(n < 2)$ is false, and thus the conditional is True. For $n <2$ there is a value for $x$ that satisfies $P(x) \land (n < x)$ ? We have only 2 and 3 for $P$ and not $(2 < 2)$. Thus, we are left with 3: $P(3) \land (n < 3)$, for $n < 2$.

Comment: What is your result?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have that:
$$M_1 \models \Phi \ and  \ M_2 \models \lnot \Phi$$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you agree with my result?

Comment: Correct..........

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA For a certain reason, my lecturer says different. He says they are both satisfy $\phi$. Maybe I didn't get what he said right. Are u sure?